# Missing character in custom font

Tags: itext

We are using iTextSharp to create PDF's using a custom font and I am running into an issue with the unicode character 2120 (SM, Service Mark). The problem is the glyph is not in the custom font. Is there a way I can specify a fallback font for a field in a PDF? We tried adding a text field with Verdana so that the form had the secondary font embedded in it but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find a font (ttf, otf,...) that has the character you need. Then you can use the `FontSelector` class and add the different fonts you want to use to this selector (see the [FontSelectionExample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=214)). Now you can process every string:

```
FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
selector.addFont(f1);
selector.addFont(f2);
Phrase ph = selector.process(some_string);
```

The `FontSelector` will return a phrase that consists of `Chunk`s with font `f1` for all the glyphs that are available in the first font, and `Chunk`s with font `f2` for the glyphs that couldn't be font in `f1`, but that are present in `f2`.

If you want the C# port of this example, please consult [chapter 11](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/).

**Update**

Using a `FontSelector` also works in the context of forms (as long as we're talking about AcroForm technology). It's really easy: you just need to add substitutions fonts to the form:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.addSubstitutionFont(bf1);
form.addSubstitutionFont(bf2);
```

Now the font defined in the form has preference, but if that font can't show a specific glyph, it will look at `bf1`, then at `bf2` and so on. You can find an example demonstrating this functionality [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=158).

Note that there's a difference between the first and the second example. In the first example we use a `Font` object, in the second, we use a `BaseFont` object.

Comment: Thanks for the information. We are not using chunks in our code, though. We are using the AcroFields.SetField() call. Can you use the FontSelector on the fields in a form?

Comment: That helped tremendously. For anyone who looks at this in the future the update example is a bit off as it requires a BaseFont, not Font object, but it was easy enough to get that figured. Thanks for the help Bruno!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added a clarification about `Font` and `BaseFont`.

Comment: How expensive is this? Would it be okay to add all my fonts to the selector, or would this be to much over head?