# iTextSharp fill form with non embedded font (override font setting from Acrobat)

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I'm trying to fill a PDF form using iTextSharp, but being cursed with the need for Scandinavian characters (åäöøæ etc) I can't use the built in Helvetica. The closest thing would be to use Arial, BUT if I embed Arial I'm stuck with a PDF template 6 times larger than the original file.

So, my question, is there a way to use Helvetica when creating the template (in order to keep the size down) and then override this in the code when filling the PDF?

As it stands right now I have this:

```
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(templateFile), new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields acroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        acroFields.SetField("txtDocumentId", dnData.DocumentId);
        acroFields.SetField("txtName", dnData.Name);

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Close();
```

I would prefer to define an unembedded font (Arial) for the fields since all end users will have Arial installed on their Machines.

Is this doable?

Comment: Did you try using Arial as a substitution font as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845688/missing-character-in-custom-font

Comment: Works wonders. Thanks a bunch, didn't even know how to formulate the question, even less about the substitution fonts. You saved my head alot of grief. :)